# WPF C# get name of image from image control

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I'm developing a WPF application and now I need to get only name and extension from a image control path.

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Width="20" Name="imgName"/>
```

I just get the real name of image for example:
This is the image path: `/bin/Debug/Image/name.jpg`
How to get only `name.jpg` and verify if is the source of imgName?
I want to get all Image controls that contains the source as name.jpg to create a function that enable a button. Someone have ideia how to do it?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but if you need the file name from the `Image`'s `Source`, you can use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imgName.Source.ToString());`. This will throw an exception if `imgName`'s `Source` property is null.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi What happens when I set the source of my image control to a BitmapSource?

Comment: Thanks @SzabolcsDézsi this it works!

Comment: @GlenThomas is right though. This won't work if the `Image`'s `Source` property is set to this for example: `imgName.Source = BitmapSource.Create(128, 128, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Indexed1, new BitmapPalette(new[] { Colors.Red, Colors.Blue, Colors.Green }), new byte[2048], 16)`